# Google Chromeのローカルストレージに保存されている内容がブラウザの表示に反映されないのはなぜでしょうか？

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

いつもお世話になっています。
下記の質問についてご教示を願います。

---

#### 【質問の主旨】

【質問の補足】で示すGitHubのコードは天気予報の情報をローカルストレージに保存するコードです。Google Chromeのローカルストレージに"Key"と"Value"の内容が保存されるものの、それらの内容がブラウザに反映されません。なぜでしょうか？

#### 【質問の補足】

1. GitHubのコード

上記の【質問の主旨】に関わる主なコードはGitHubにて公開しています。

- [index.html](https://github.com/echizenyayota/work/blob/master/index.html)
- [scripts/app.js](https://github.com/echizenyayota/work/blob/master/scripts/app.js)

2. コードの出典について

上記のコードの出典元はGoogleの開発者向けサイトの[はじめてのプログレッシブ ウェブアプリ「5. 最初の読み込みを高速に行えるようにする」](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/your-first-pwapp-ja/#4)です。

3. テストの実行について

上記の「5. 最初の読み込みを高速に行えるようにする」の「テストの実行」という見出しでは、実行結果が以下のとおり説明されています。

```
- 初回実行時には、initialWeatherForecast からの予報が即座に表示されます。
- 新しい都市を追加（右上の + アイコンをクリック）し、2つのカードが表示されることを確認します。
- ブラウザを更新し、アプリに両方の予報が読み込まれて最新情報が表示されることを確認します。
```

2番目に「2つのカードが表示される」と説明されていますが、個人的にはニューヨーク以外の他の都市を選んでも **2つのカードが表示されないのではないか** と考えています。app.jsで示したコードには「2つのカードが表示される」ような記述は見当たらない気がするからです。

4. [サンプルを見る]について

[サンプルを見る]というページの最下部にあるボタンを押して、サンプルページを表示させ、ニューヨーク以外の他の都市を選んでも2つのカードは表示されません。

5. ローカルストレージの内容

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

自分のローカル開発環境でlocalstorageの内容を確認をすると上記の画像になります。

---

以上、ご確認のほどよろしくお願い申し上げます

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`app.getForecast`内で使われている Yahoo Weather API への呼び出しが、2019年1月3日から[query.yahooapis.com 経由で行えなくなった](https://developer.yahoo.com/weather/)ためだと思われます。Chrome の Console タブや Network タブで、query.yahooapis.com への XHR が失敗しているのが確認できます。

Comment: tsushima さん。コメントありがとうございます。
>Chrome の Console タブや Network タブで、query.yahooapis.com への XHR が失敗しているのが確認できます。おっしゃるととおりにそれぞれを確認すると、query.yahooapis.comとの通信が失敗していることが分かりました。自分の目標はYAHOOからお天気情報情報を表示することではなく、プログレッシブアプリを理解することです。このままGoogleのチュートリアルを進めるかどうかは検討します。